# Ubuntu 21.10 is freezing randomly after the last update (Nov 2, 2021)

Tags: freeze, 21.10

My computer is a Toshiba Satellite L635. Ubuntu free, but the problem remains the same. It started this morning, 2 nov 2021, after `apt-get update`. There are particular messages in /var/log/syslog. I may attach a complete dpkg.log, `lshw` and `hwinfo` if necessary.

Results of `hwinfo` :

```
    ============ start debug info ============
    libhd version 21.72 (x86-64) [7688]
    using /var/lib/hardware
    kernel version is 5.13
    ----- /proc/cmdline -----
      BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-20-generic root=UUID=883bf2b4-40e2-42a0-a516-9fdf403023db ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
    ----- /proc/cmdline end -----
```

@heynnema Thanks for your help.

```
xyko@xyko-Satellite-L635:~$ sudo free -h
[sudo] senha para xyko: 
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem.:          3,6Gi       1,4Gi       273Mi       123Mi       2,0Gi       1,9Gi
Swap:          6,8Gi       0,0Ki       6,8Gi
xyko@xyko-Satellite-L635:~$ sudo sysctl vm.swappiness 
vm.swappiness = 60
xyko@xyko-Satellite-L635:~$ sudo swapon -s
Nome do arquivo             Tipo        Tamanho     Usado   Prioridade
/dev/sda2
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131214/discussion-on-question-by-xyko-ubuntu-21-10-is-freezing-randomly-after-the-last).